# How to embedded a link in a XUL treecell?

Tags: tree, xul

The question is simple. I want to put a link in a XUL treecell.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've only gotten this to work with onclick events:

```
<text value="http://getsatisfaction.com/"
        class="url"
        onclick="window.open('http://getsatisfaction.com/');"/>
```

And, of course, these should probably be applied via js instead of hard-coding.

hrm. [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/href) give an alternate example:

```
<label href="http://`enter code here`example.com" 
        class="text-link" 
        value="Click here to go to example.com"/>
```