# How to embed hyperlink in the entire trecell of treeitem of treecol in XUL Tree

Tags: hyperlink, tree, xul

I have a XUL tree formed using XML template. I have treecol for URL's and I want to embed those url's as a hyperlink.

```
    <tree id="myTodoListTree" flex="1" seltype="multiple"
datasources="file://C:/mercredi.xml" ref="*" querytype="xml"  >        
        <treecol  id="url" label="Facebook" flex="1" />
        <template>
        <query expr="CONTACT"> 
        <assign var="?facebook" expr="./URL/text()"/> 
        </query> 
        <action> 
         <treechildren id="myTodoListTreeChildren">
              <treeitem uri="?">
                <treerow> 
            <treecell value="true"  editable="false" label="?facebook"/>
        </treerow>
              </treeitem>
            </treechildren>
        </action>
      </template> 
    </tree>
```

This thread has similar problem but no proper solution. 
[How to embedded a link in a XUL treecell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551928/how-to-embedded-a-link-in-a-xul-treecell)
Even in the Mozilla website referred by the above link has no proper solution.

I couldn't find any refrence in XUL School mozilla website.
For emaple, this is one of the url item in the tree-cell: It's a duplicate value

> http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=101112487211054

Using CSS I can assign something to the entire treecolumn like this: it works.

```
treechildren:-moz-tree-column {
border-right:1px solid rgb(220,220,220) !important;
}
```

When i tried to assign to the specific column, it's not working.

```
#url>treechildren::-moz-tree-column(hover){
cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector is wrong: `#url>treechildren::-moz-tree-column(hover)`. The cell with id `url` does not have `<treechildren>` in it, the `<treechildren>` has a cell in it. Try something like this instead: `treechildren .url::-moz-tree-column(hover)`, which selects any cell with the classs `url`.